# XAML ListView setting visibility and height of second "Description" textblock based on first textblock clicking

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, windows-8.1

I have a grouped collection which I want to display in a list view, such that each item is wrapped in a panel. The item panel has two components i.e. Product heading button/texblock or whatever that can be clicked and on clicking the header it will show the item Description and clicking back will show only heading. I can't use expander because it is window 8.1.

One way to do that is to set the visibility of `Description` when `Name` is clicked.
Q1: How do I bind each item within ListView so that it will not effect other listview items and clicking on header will show/hide description?

Q2: In the following code the textblock height for each item in a group is set to the first item height. If the first item height is 5 lines then every item in the group has textblock with 5 lines, how to fix that issue?

Model Definition:

```
public class Product {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

}
```

CollectionViewSource Definition:

```
    <Page.Resources>
        <CollectionViewSource x:Name="cvs"
                          IsSourceGrouped="True"
                          ItemsPath="Items"/>
    </Page.Resources>
```

ListView Definition:

```
            <ListView x:Name="myListView"
                  Grid.Row="1"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource cvs}}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Width="500">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5"/>
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}" FontSize="26.67"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                        <GroupStyle.Panel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <VariableSizedWrapGrid Orientation="Vertical" ItemWidth="500"/>
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.Panel>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
            </ListView>
```

**Update 1:**

Updated ItemTemplate

```
                 <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <ToggleButton Name="NameToggleButton" Content="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=NameToggleButton, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

Here is the converter class

```
public class EmptyStackToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            var backStack = value as Stack<ContentRef>;
            return backStack.Any() ? Visibility.Collapsed : Visibility.Visible;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Q1: I'd just make an unstyled `ToggleButton` and give it an `x:Name` to replace the TextBlock for "Name" in your `ItemTemplate` and bind visibility of the Description TextBlock to it with a converter via `Visibility="{Binding Visibility, ElementName=ToggleButtonName, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}"` and call it done. Q2 though is going to require more involvement than I can offer at the moment if you're determined to stick with ListView as the parent.

Comment: How do I set `ToggleButtonName`, I tried `x:Name={Binding Name}` but I can't bind name to model.

Comment: You don't bind anything on the name. Just x:Name="ToggleButtonName" on the ToggleButton and then the visibility binding just uses ElementName to reference it via ElementName=ToggleButtonName on the TextBlock. :)

Comment: Oh I did just notice an error I made though, it should be actually Bound to **IsChecked** property of the ToggleButton, not Visibility, sorry about that. Like `Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=ToggleButtonName, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}"`

Comment: I tried and only the first toggle button in a group work properly

Comment: There's a built in [class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the converter. I'm on my phone but it seems like that may be your issue. Your ItemTemplate is a DataTemplate, so it's its own little world of datacontext and each should perform the task individually.